# May logrotate rotate log in the middle of the line?

Tags: linux, logrotate

I working on a GUI for viewing audit.log, which can be rotated. Should I take care of situation when one part of some line is in one file, and the rest of the line is in another file?

Answer (score 0):

I use Fedora and Debian systems, but i have not seen such a case.

So i think you do not have to worry about that, `logrotate` solve this.